# Trying to put error messages if index is out of bound, named removed doesn't exist, limit adding names to 5 and displaying names individually

Tags: python, list

```
student = [] 
opt = 1
while(opt!=0):
    print("1.Add | 2.Edit | 3.Delete | 4:Display | 0:Exit")
    opt = int(input("option:")
    if(opt==1):
        student.append(input("addname:"))
    elif(opt==2):
        edit = int(input("index to edit:"))
        student[edit] = input("Updated name:")
    elif(opt==3):
        student.remove(input("Enter Name:"))
    elif(opt==4):
        for x in range(0,len(student)):
            print(student[(len(student)-1)-x])
```

so I'm trying to create a code where it will put an error message if index to edit is out of bound, if the named remove doesn't exist and limiting the add name just up to 5.
as well displaying name individual but at my opt==4 it's displaying them backward and if I removed the negative sign it comes out as an error saying perhaps I have forgotten a comma.

Comment: Where are you facing problem  ?

Comment: Specifically in this code "print(student[(len(student)-1)-x])" when i do remove the negative sign it says that perhaps I forgot a comma

Comment: Yes it should say like that

Comment: it works but it displays the names from last to first and I want it to display first to last as well I'm trying to add some things like displaying error messages but I don't know how to put them for like i want to put an error message that limits the user to only enter 5 names so it prints that out and won't let the user to add another name in the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
student = [] 
opt = 1
while(opt!=0):
    print("1.Add | 2.Edit | 3.Delete | 4:Display | 0:Exit")
    opt = int(input("option:")
    if(opt==1):
         if len(student) < 5:
            student.append(input("addname:"))
    elif(opt==2):
        edit = int(input("index to edit:"))
        if edit < len(student):
            student[edit] = input("Updated name:")
        else :
            print ("Index out of bound")
    elif(opt==3):
        student.remove(input("Enter Name:"))
    elif(opt==4):
        for x in range(0,len(student)):
            print(student[x])
```